Modify cart item subtotal format in the WooCommerce cart block
In the cart shortcode, I use the woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal hook to display the item subtotal using wc_format_sale_price(), because I'm showing a deal.
Here is the code:
$subtotal = \wc_format_sale_price(
    $price1,
    $price2,
);

Here is a screenshot:

Now, I need to put this item subtotal format in the cart block, here I found and example to modify it:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const { registerCheckoutFilters } = window.wc.blocksCheckout;

    // Adjust cart item price of the cart line items.
    registerCheckoutFilters( 'example-extension', {
        cartItemPrice: ( value, extensions, args ) => {

            // Return early since this filter is not being applied in the Cart context.
            // We must return the original value we received here.
            if ( args?.context !== 'cart' ) {
                return value;
            }

            return '<price/> for all items';
        }
    } );
});

But, if I change <price /> for any other value, it shows an error.
How can I use the SalePrice component in this section?
